# What is the best solution to adopt for email marketing in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I am in a requirement to develop something that will help me to send emails to subscribed customers for their abandoned carts, pending wishlist items, promotional email whenever required, etc.

What is the best way to adopt for this, any idea?

Any suggestions like Mailchimp, Mandrill,etc?

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html try this extension. You have to remove some of the functionality and have to add functionality like for wish list and promotional email. But i thinks its a good to start for your requirement

Comment: You can get all data from db. for example list of items in cart,wishlis since last week of customer now you can run cron to check priodically and send email based on this data you can make module for it.